# The line $y=k$ intersects the curve $y=2x-3x^3$ in the first quadrant

Tags: definite-integrals, area

[image]

The line $y=k$ intersects the curve $y=2x-3x^3$ in the first quadrant as shown in the figure.What is the value of $k$ for which area of the shaded regions are equal?

My try:I tried to find point of intersections of line $y=k$ and curve $y=2x-3x^3$ but could not find.So could not move ahead with solving.Can someone assist me in solving this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$
2z-3z^3=k,
$$
and $z_1$, $z_2$ are positive roots ($z_1<z_2$). Condition for areas is
$$
kz_1 - \int_0^{z_1} y\,dx = \int_{z_1}^{z_2} y\,dx - k(z_2-z_1);
$$
hence
$$
kz_1 + k(z_2-z_1) = \int_0^{z_1} y\,dx + \int_{z_1}^{z_2} y\,dx\\
kz_2 = \int_0^{z_2} y\,dx
$$
Now called that $y=2x-3x^3$:
$$
kz_2 = z_2^2 -\frac34 z_2^4
$$
And we have the system
$$
kz_2 = z_2^2 -\frac34 z_2^4\\
k=2z_2-3z_2^3
$$
Solve it:
$$
kz_2=2z_2^2-3z_2^4=z_2^2 -\frac34 z_2^4 \Longrightarrow z_2^2=\frac94 z_2^4.
$$
$z_2\ne 0$ and $z_2>0$; so, $z_2=2/3$ and $k=4/9$. Let's plot this:

$\hspace{1in}$[image]